# Demoted SASS version; Now there's Ruby error

Tags: css, ruby, sass, watch

My SASS was working really slow, some people online suggested to demote to Sass 3.1.0 (Brainy Betty) because it works faster.
I uninstalled and installed this version. 
When I uninstalled it asked whether or not to delete SASS executables, I hit yes.
Now when I use the --watch command, this is the message I get:

> Sass is watching for changes. Press Ctrl-C to stop.
>   NoMethodError: undefined method `empty?' for nil:NilClass
>     Use --trace for backtrace.

My SASS is no longer working and I am not familiar with Ruby. Thanks

Comment: You do understand that 3.1.x has considerably less features than 3.2, 3.3, or even 3.4, right?  It will be almost impossible to find a library that *doesn't* take advantage of features that only exist in 3.2 or later.

Comment: try re-installing and not clicking yes? also, you may hit bugs because the files you're compiling rely on >3.1 stuff, Sass can pop up some confusing Ruby error messages when it fails - the slowness probably has a better solution

Comment: Thanks @ToniLeigh, I just uninstalled & re-installed the newest version, seems to work now without any issues. Cheers